# How do add Image inside Image in SwiftUI

Tags: image, swiftui

I am new in SwiftUI and I have two Image and I want to create Image like shown in the below image

[image]

I have tried it using code like this

```
Image("Background_Image")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(width: 101, height: 107)
    .overlay {
        Image("Person_Pic")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 95, height: 110)
            .opacity(0.9)
            .offset(y: -9)
    }
```

But it is show like this

[image]

How can I set Image like the first Image.

asset Image

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should attach the asset files so that anyone who is suggesting a solution might try with your asset images.

Comment: @B25Dec Please check I added asset images as you asked

Comment: Though the size of the asset you shared was very small I used the same in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `mask` to clip the top picture to the background image.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var bckimg: some View {
        Image("Background_Image")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 101, height: 107)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        bckimg
            .overlay {
                Image("Person_Pic")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 95, height: 110)
                    .opacity(0.9)
                    .offset(y: -9)
                    .mask { bckimg }
            }
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your code but her head is outside the mask. how can I achieve it

Comment: Try making a second background image ("Background_Image2")
 and edit it to add some color where her head is going to be,
 and use that as the mask, `.mask { bckimg2 }`

Comment: Not working can you show how?

Answer (score 0):

yes, @sumida was right masking is one way to do that. But I think you have to draw a path in the bottom half of your background so that per path it can get masked. Though you only need to mask the bottom half you can think of a custom path with the bottom half of your background image. This is my thought on your problem. But you can try the bottom one too if that works for you. Hope it helps.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let backgroundImg = Image("Background_Image")
        let personImg = Image("Person_Pic")
        
        ZStack {
            backgroundImg
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            personImg
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .mask(
                    backgroundImg
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .offset(y: -50)
                        .clipped()
                )
        }
    }
}
```

It's kind of working for me, See if it helps you. Attaching a screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Comment: Adding a offset of masking can also create the same effect you are looking for.